# Show Yes or No for a boolean column in a DevXpress grid

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, gridview, devexpress

I am using a "DevXpress.XtraGrid.GridView"  and I have a column there which is bound to a boolean data. This column shows check boxes to represent values. I need to show "YES/NO" instead of check boxes. Please advice me.

Thanks for helping,
Kushan Randima.

Comment: Give a link to the exact type. `Grid` is ambiguous.

Comment: "DevXpress.XtraGrid.GridView"

Comment: nope, i am not, but don't have hard feeling about downvotes, that is not personal... ask more questions then you know how to avoid downvotes, i had received quite a few downvotes when i first use StackOveflow.

Comment: Hope [this](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3045) helps.

Comment: @KushanRandima - Dont worry about a downvote or two. People will still answer your question unless it is closed. People will downvote without closing. I don't think there is anything wrong with this question. +1 to negate the downvote. As to your question, DevExpress's online docs shows how to do what you want. I have done it several times. Have you checked their documentation?

Comment: I am a beginner, who get lots of benefits from stack overflow. I don't need to collect reputations/badges. (If I can donate them, I will donate them who ever wanted :-D) My concern is that stack overflow is blocking me from asking questions by such downvotes. It is the pain. By the way, I want to appreciate you. You are a kind person. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I understand how you feel, but don't be so sensitive. Just let it roll off. When you act frustrated or sensitive on SO you will surely get a few downvotes quickly. Now, on to the answer, see below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it in code in one of my tools. This is a dynamic SQL Query tool and it returns a checkmark or red X beside the query result, at runtime. You can also do this through the designer but this is done in code.

This is for Winforms, but the low level GridView should be the same code for WPF (I am not positive).

First, in the Data Grid GridView designer, I add a column (mine is "IsError" column). Then in my form constructor or InitializeForm() I do this:

```
RepositoryItemCheckEdit checkEdit = gridOutput.RepositoryItems.Add("CheckEdit") as RepositoryItemCheckEdit;

checkEdit.PictureChecked = global::Gyrasoft.Common.DX.Properties.Resources.exclamation;
checkEdit.PictureUnchecked = global::Gyrasoft.Common.DX.Properties.Resources.accept;

checkEdit.CheckStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CheckStyles.UserDefined;
gridViewOutput.Columns["IsError"].ColumnEdit = checkEdit;
```

The resources, of course, have to be valid images.

Basically you add a repository item (`RepositoryItemCheckEdit`) and set `CheckStyle` to `UserDefined`, and assign the checkEdit to the gridView column. You can add the same checkedit to multiple columns. It is simply for rendering or editing.

Comment: This is my code

 `public frmViewBookings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            RepositoryItemCheckEdit checkEdit = gridControl1.RepositoryItems.Add("CheckEdit") as RepositoryItemCheckEdit;

            checkEdit.ValueChecked = "Yes";
            checkEdit.ValueUnchecked = "No";

            checkEdit.CheckStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CheckStyles.UserDefined;
            gridView1.Columns["LT"].ColumnEdit = checkEdit;
        }`

'LT' is the boolean column. But after adding this code it shows nothing in that column.

Comment: Ensure that the PictureChecked and PictureUnchecked properties are correct images.

Comment: Since I want to show YES or NO in the boolean column, I changed the code as `checkEdit.ValueChecked = "Yes";` `checkEdit.ValueUnchecked = "No";` So I don't use pictures. Thank You.